# programmatically add class name to fields

Tags: theming

I want to add custom class name to fields in user login form other than default class name.
For example,

- `user-name-field` for Username field
- `password-field` for Password field
- `click-me-button` for Submit button
- c`reat-account-link` for Create new account
- `request-password` for Request new password

how to do this programmatically?

Comment: Could you post details of the code you're currently using, and exactly which parts of it aren't working please?

Comment: Please don't use code blocks for things that are not code. I agree that class names *may* be considered code. I edited your question with that assumption in mind.

Comment: I used following code in theme's template.php file function THEME_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id, $element) {
if ( TRUE === in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_login', 'user_login_block') ) ) { $form['name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('class1', 'class2'); $form['pass']['#attributes']['class'] = array('class3', 'class4');}} Now class names are assigned to text field.  I want to assign class name to Create new account and Request new password links separately. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Alter the login form using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). And use [#attributes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) to add custom classes to fields.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template file (e.g. block--user--login.tpl.php). Then you can add custom classes to the

```
<div id="user-login-block-container">
    <form action="<?php print $form['#action']; ?>" method="post" id="<?php print $form['#id']; ?>"
      accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name customclass">
        <?php print render($form['name']); // Name field ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass customclass">
        <?php print render($form['pass']); // Password field ?>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login_block"/>

    <div class="form-item form-actions form-wrapper" id="login_button">
        <input value="Login" type="submit" class="submit-button customclass" title="Login"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then put in the template.php of your theme, the function:

```
yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
$user_login = user_login_block(array());

$form = drupal_build_form('user_login_block', $user_login);

$form['name']['#required'] = false;
$form['pass']['#required'] = false;

$vars['form'] = $form;
```

Finally include the template file in your page.tpl.php:

```
<?php include 'block--user--login.tpl.php'; ?>
```

Comment: I used following code in theme's template.php file. function THEME_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id, $element) { if ( TRUE === in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_login', 'user_login_block') ) ) { $form['name']['#attributes']['class'] = array('class1', 'class2'); $form['pass']['#attributes']['class'] = array('class3', 'class4');}} Now class names are assigned to text field. I want to assign class name to Create new account and Request new password links separately. How can I do this?